# Make a particular div background transparent in Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my HTML (Bootstrap) document:

```
<div modal="showModal" close="cancel()">
    <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h2>Members who shortlisted you </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="kitty.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ok()">Okay</button>
      <button class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the background of the modal-header part transparent so that I can see the text and images behind the popup. I already tried the following CSS:

```
.modal-header {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

but its not working, if someone would help me then it great

Comment: opacity will help you to fading the text, not making a particular div a transparent

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `opacity` is not the same a `background-color`.

Comment: @AJAYKUMAR In that case I have updated your question to specifically state that only want to make the background transparent.

Answer (score 1):

`background-color: #000000;` is not transparent.

Try either `background-color:transparent` (which would be the default).

Alternatively `:background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)`.

You should note however that this will only show the background of the parent div....whatever that is.

Comment: sorry, Its not working.
applying rgba(0,0,0,0) makes background white not transparent

Comment: What you are probably seeing is the background of the **parent** which I expect is white. You can't 'cut holes' in backgrounds.

Comment: u r right and while using inspect element, when I remove the background color part then it works fine but not in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

`background-color: #000000` does not make the background transparent, it only sets the `background-color` to `black`.

You can use one of 3 things:

`background-color: transparent` - Sets the background color to transparent

`background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` - The last `0` sets `opacity` to `0`

`opacity: 0` - This sets the `opacity` of the whole div to `0`

Comment: sorry, Its not working.
applying rgba(0,0,0,0) makes background white not transparent